# TextBox c# refer string

Tags: c#, textbox

Is it possible to like refer a string as content for a TextBox in c#? I have a listbox with a bunch of objects in it. And each object contain a string. And when I select an object in the listbox I want its string to be the content in the TextBox, so that whatever I write gets saved to the string.

Like for example in Java you could have a PlainDocument in an object, and whenever you select a different object in a JList you could set the document in a JTextField to the objects PlainDocument.

Comment: Are you talking about of an ASP.NET app, WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) for an automated solution or you can manually listen for [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the list box and set the [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the event handler.

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, e) => {
   object selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem;
   textBox1.Text = selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.ToString() : null;
};
```

Comment: Ty, Data Binding is perfect

Answer (score 0):

The content of the textbox can be accessed using

```
myTextBox.Text
```

This property expects string, so your answer is Yes. I think simply assigning this property would do.

**UPDATE**

I think you need something like this(assuming you are using WinForms):

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        listBox1.Items.Insert(index, textBox1.Text);            
    }
```

Though there is an action for TextChanged event of textbox in WinForms, but changing listbox from there is a bit tricky (ends up calling each other infinitely) as we are already changing textbox from the change event of listbox.

Adding a button to do this simplifies it a lot.

Comment: That will just copy the string from/to the TextBox. I want it to use the same string as in my object so I dont have to save it everytime it changes etc.

Comment: Am sorry, but I didn't get the requirement. Do you want to change the content of a textbox eachtime a new item is selected from a listbox?

Comment: Yes and each time I write to the TextBox I want the text to get stored in the selected object's string.

Comment: Hi @coalazero I think a button to update the string in listbox would be a easy solution, I updated my answer, please check if that is helpful...

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx